# BeagleBone Black and JavaFX 2D rendering acceleration

Tags: java, javafx, opengl-es-2.0, beagleboneblack

I just wondering if it's possible to run JavaFX with 2D GPU acceleration. So far I managed to run JavaFX but the basic test app is **unusably slow** because of error *Could not get EGL surface* and fallback to Software rendering.

**Configuration**

- BeagleboneBlack + 4D 7" touchscreen LCD
- Debian 8.4 official image (kernel 4.4.9)
- OracleJDK8 and Gluon JavaFX armhf plugin
- Kernel updated to 4.4.9-bone10 ([this way](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/sOhHuq_T6KQ))
- SGX drivers installed via (GFX_5.01.01.02_es8.x.tar), libgles2-mesa is present

**Verification if omaplfb & pvrsrvkm loaded**

```
    $ lsmod | grep omaplfb
    omaplfb                12142  0
    tilcdc                 26645  1 omaplfb
    pvrsrvkm              155855  1 omaplfb
```

Modules seems to be loaded, but there is *tilcdc* added against list in this [tutorial](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardDebian#SGX_BeagleBone.2FBeagleBone_Black).

**Verbose output from running JFX**

App is deployed remotely via Netbeans with VM option *-Dprism.verbose=true*.
I went through all kinds of error messages over last few days: egl_bad_access, egl_bad_alloc and now egl_bad_config (0x3005). Now when i deploy the app it shows this:

```
Prism pipeline init order: 
es2 
sw 
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Using system sized mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2_monocle succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory 
com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.GLException: 0x3005: Could not get EGL surface
at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.AcceleratedScreen.<init>(AcceleratedScreen.java:110)
at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.NativePlatform.getAcceleratedScreen(NativePlatform.java:127)
at com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory.initialize(MonocleGLFactory.java:107)
at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:81)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
 vsync: true vpipe: false
Loading Prism common native library ...
succeeded.
```

At this point I'm stuck. What could possibly cause error *"Could not get EGL surface"*? Is it even possible to get 2D GPU acceleration on BBB w.SGX, maybe I'm trying something unreal.

Any help would be much appreciated!